# I am trying to launch Jenkins slave via Jenkins and getting this error , I opened all the required ports, also installed Jenkins on agent machine

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

> SSHLauncher{host='172.31.45.245', port=22, credentialsId='1', jvmOptions='',  javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60,  maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15,  sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
> [03/24/21 16:14:07] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 172.31.45.245:22.
> [03/24/21 16:14:07] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
> ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for ubuntu (credentialId:1/method:publickey)
> [03/24/21 16:14:07] [SSH] Authentication failed.
> Authentication failed.
> [03/24/21 16:14:07] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
> [03/24/21 16:14:07] [SSH] Connection closed

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the below settings in each of the slave machine.

*Host Key Verification Strategy - Non Verifying Verification Strategy*

[Jenkins-43062](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43062) 
[CloudBees Snippet](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000073552-Host-Key-Verification-for-SSH-Agents)

Comment: it was already Non Verifying Verification Strategy